# BigQueryIO: Query configured via options, but "Value only available at runtime"

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam 2.9.0

I have set up a pipeline that pulls data from BigQuery and does a series of transforms on it. The options have a start date attached to them using a `ValueProvider`:

```
ValueProvider<String> getStartTime();

void setStartTime(ValueProvider<String> startTime);
```

I then go to pull the data with `BigQueryIO` (changing things around a bit for the sake of making it explicit what is going on):

```
BigQueryIO.read(
            (SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, AggregatedRowRecord>)
                input -> new BigQueryParser().apply(input.getRecord()))
        .withoutValidation()
        .withTemplateCompatibility()
        .fromQuery(
            ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider.of(
                opts.getStartTime(),
                (SerializableFunction<String, String>)
                    input -> {
                      Instant instant = Instant.parse(input);

                      return String.format(
                          <large SQL statement with a %s in it>,
                          String.format(
                              "%d_%d_%d",
                              instant.get(ChronoField.YEAR),
                              instant.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR),
                              instant.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    }))
        .withCoder(<coder for AggregatedRowRecords>)
        .usingStandardSql()
```

This is then added to a pipeline normally (`p.apply(<above>)`).

Now I run it:

```
--project=<project> \
--tempLocation=<directory> \
--stagingLocation=<directory> \
--network=dataflow \
--subnetwork=<subnetwork> \
--defaultWorkerLogLevel=DEBUG
--appName=<name>
--runner=DirectRunner
```

This causes the following error:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=startTime, default=null}
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:332)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:302)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:197)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:64)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:313)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:299)
        at <class>.main(<class>.java:<>)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=startTime, default=null}
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$RuntimeValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:228)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySource.createBasicQueryConfig(BigQueryQuerySource.java:230)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySource.dryRunQueryIfNeeded(BigQueryQuerySource.java:175)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySource.getTableToExtract(BigQueryQuerySource.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.extractFiles(BigQuerySourceBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead$2.processElement(BigQueryIO.java:783)
```

The use of `NestedValueProvider` comes from [this example on setting up templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates):

`The user provides a substring for a BigQuery query, such as a specific date. The transform uses the substring to create the full query. Calling .get() returns the full query.`

Removing the value provider logic doesn't seem to help, however.  Removing the `ValueProvider` entirely from the `withQuery` section works fine, but defeats the purpose of being able to set it via options.

Comment: What's the command to run it for? I suspect this might be happening if you are trying to run the job without staging the template first and not providing any default/dummy value for `startTime`. Error thrown [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b953645ed6db837d24284d7fe1fe091e7309f821/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProvider.java#L227)

Comment: Hey did you solve the issue?

Answer (score -2):

The exception explains you the issue, Apache beam first builds the pipeline and the classes and then start to run the data in the pipeline, in this stage, you can't access to options, this is just metadata for building the pipeline.

The way to overcome it is to create a ParDo function/ PTransform, that will get the options you need as parameters in the constructor, then it can access it in its logic.

See example: (my use case, I face the same issue last days)

The pipeline:

```
   HistoryProcessingOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(HistoryProcessingOptions.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

  pipeline.apply(SourceRead.of(options.getSourceBigQueryTable().get(),
            options.getSourceBigQueryDataset().get(),
            options.getSourceBigQueryProject().get(),
            options.getFromDate().get(),
            options.getToDate().get()
            ))
```

The transformer itself:

```
public class SourceRead extends PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<TableRow>> {

private String sourceBigQueryTable;

private String sourceBigQueryDataset;

private String sourceBigQueryProject;

private String formDate;

private String toDate;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SourceRead.class);


public SourceRead(String sourceBigQueryTable, String sourceBigQueryDataset, String sourceBigQueryProject, String formDate, String toDate) {
    this.sourceBigQueryTable = sourceBigQueryTable;
    this.sourceBigQueryDataset = sourceBigQueryDataset;
    this.sourceBigQueryProject = sourceBigQueryProject;
    this.formDate = formDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
}

public static SourceRead of(String sourceBigQueryTable, String sourceBigQueryDataset, String sourceBigQueryProject, String yearToLoad, String dateToLoad) {
    return new SourceRead(sourceBigQueryTable, sourceBigQueryDataset, sourceBigQueryProject, yearToLoad, dateToLoad);
}





@Override
public PCollection<TableRow> expand(PBegin input) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([" + sourceBigQueryProject + ":"+sourceBigQueryDataset+"."+sourceBigQueryTable+"],"
            + "TIMESTAMP('" + formDate + "'),"
            + "TIMESTAMP('" + toDate + "'))";
    logger.info("query is"+ query);
    return input.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
            .fromQuery(query));
}
```